# How to identify when App gets uninstalled

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, resource-cleanup

I want to execute a function when my App gets uninstalled by user.

Using Cordova, Is there a way through which we can **detect uninstall event and execute something?** for example, to clean up resources.

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm...what platform are your targeting? It would be different based on the mobile OS.

Comment: I am targeting for iOS initially. Any suggestions, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this with or without Cordova. iOS will clean up all of your files for you.